# My Ubuntu 18.10 does not display the GUI login, but works only in command line mode

Tags: command-line, display, gui, 18.10

I have logged in into my Ubuntu using terminal login itself. And I tried out the shortcuts ***Ctrl+Alt+F3*** and ***Ctrl+Alt+F7*** which I found that it was to switch from GUI to command line mode.

Comment: Do you have a desktop version of Ubuntu 18.10 installed? as server releases do not include any gui desktop by default.  Also try ctrl+alt+F1 which switches to my gui on my lubuntu 19.10 box.  (older versions yes use ctrl+alt+f7 but it was switched to f1 as I recall for gui)

Comment: I had a desktop version installed only but, for the past few days, it is booting only in CLI mode. Sure, I will try that out.